# Writing data types to a CSV

Tags: python, arrays, types

My program generates a workout routine. This workout routine is saved in a 2D array. The workout routine is then written to a CSV file. However, when the user logs in, the workout routine gets pulled from the CSV file as a string. Therefore, there is no way for me to pull individual exercises from the array. 
The workout routine is written to an array called `user_information`

This is what the retrieved `user_information` looks like (it is saved as a string format)

```
[['Bench Press', 'Dumbell Press', 'Rotating Incline Dumbell Press', 'Inner Chest Upwards Barbell Push', 'Reverse Flies', 'Cable Side Raise', 'Overhead Barbell Extensions'], ['Drop Set Curls', 'Close Grip Chin Ups', 'Upright Row', 'Pullups', 'One Arm Cable Pull', 'Lat Pulldowns'], ['Calf Raisers', 'Leg Extensions', 'Squats', 'Rear Kicks', 'Abductor']]"]
```

Is there anyway i can write the datatype to the CSV file, or retrieve it in such a way that makes it an array when retrieved? Or can i convert the string to an array?

Comment: "Dumbbell" has two b's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ast` module to convert the string to list object.

**Ex:**

```
import ast 

#Data read from CSV
user_information  = "[['Bench Press', 'Dumbell Press', 'Rotating Incline Dumbell Press', 'Inner Chest Upwards Barbell Push', 'Reverse Flies', 'Cable Side Raise', 'Overhead Barbell Extensions'], ['Drop Set Curls', 'Close Grip Chin Ups', 'Upright Row', 'Pullups', 'One Arm Cable Pull', 'Lat Pulldowns'], ['Calf Raisers', 'Leg Extensions', 'Squats', 'Rear Kicks', 'Abductor']]"
print(ast.literal_eval(user_information))
print(type(ast.literal_eval(user_information)))
```

**Output:**

```
[['Bench Press', 'Dumbell Press', 'Rotating Incline Dumbell Press', 'Inner Chest Upwards Barbell Push', 'Reverse Flies', 'Cable Side Raise', 'Overhead Barbell Extensions'], ['Drop Set Curls', 'Close Grip Chin Ups', 'Upright Row', 'Pullups', 'One Arm Cable Pull', 'Lat Pulldowns'], ['Calf Raisers', 'Leg Extensions', 'Squats', 'Rear Kicks', 'Abductor']]
<type 'list'>
```